# How can I retrieve my network drive credentials in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, nas, credentials, mapped-drive

My network drive login information is not showing up in Windows 10 credentials manager.

I have multiple networked drives, and I need to view the login information. How can I look up my own login information or back it up?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try **Network Password Recovery** or **VaultPasswordView**?

---

These are easy to use tools  developed by **[Nir Sofer](https://www.nirsoft.net/about_nirsoft_freeware.html)**.
Freely available at [nirsoft.net](https://nirsoft.net).

---

- **Network Password Recovery** will recover several network related passwords (credentials) from running instances of Windows 10/8/7/Vista/XP.  (**[link](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_password_recovery.html)**)
- **VaultPasswordView** will decrypt and display the contents of the 'Windows Vault' on Windows 11/10/8/7. (**[link](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/vault_password_view.html)**)

---

**Note:** Some antivirus programs may show warnings or block these programs because they read locations where passwords/secrets are stored. ([More info](https://blog.nirsoft.net/2009/05/17/antivirus-companies-cause-a-big-headache-to-small-developers/)).

Answer (score 1):

Open Control Panel, Credential Manager, Windows Credentials tab.  Server Credentials are stored here.

The login credential is there, along with the Server it belongs to.

You can also back credentials up in here (Windows Vault).

The actual path can vary and if the path was cleared (so the connection is gone) it is not stored anywhere I know of.

In a Command Prompt, type NET USE to see if any recent connections are there.

Comment: The field is formed only by dots, it isn't readable.  There is a method to read the password?

Comment: Nirsoft has tools (Apps) to reveal passwords.   Try that. It has worked for me.